# Complex Data Manipulation in Python

Tags: python, file, dictionary, multiple-columns

I have 3 files with real data and pseudo data and value of real data.

`File_one` has two columns with one column as real data and the second column as the translational data. I.e. For the real data a pseudo value is given.

```
col[0] col[1]
123     0
234     1
345     2
456     3
567     4
678     5
```

`File_two` has pairs of pseudo values i.e. In place of `123` the value used is `0` and the same way the pseudo value pairs as `[0, 1]` which means `[123, 234]` in real.

```
col[0]  col[1]
0        2
0        3
0        5
2        4
5        1
```

So can say that `col[0] and col[1]` of `file_two` are the key and the value is in `file_one` `col[0]`

Now I have to match the pseudo value pairs from `file_two` with the real data `col[0]` in `file_one` and get an output saving it to new file. We name it `file_four`. Here pairs occur only `ONE` time.

```
col[0]  col[1]
123     345
123     456
123     678
345     567
678     234
```

Now `file_three` comes into the picture. `File_three` has the 3 columns.

`col[0]` and `col[1]` are the same pairs as in `file_four` but they also have many other pairs that are not present in `file_four`.

File_three

```
col[0]  col[1]  col[2]
123     345       54
345     262       65
123     456       54
2456    2467      98
123     678       46
7845    2458      631
345     567       153
3456    3673      94
678     234       5
```

Finally, I need to match the pairs of `file_four` i.e. `col[0] col[1]` and pull the value from `col[2]` in `file_three` and generate a new `output_file` with the pairs of `file_four` as key and the value in `col[2]` of `file_three`.

In the following code I am trying to only consider first two files

```
from collections import defaultdict

d1 = dict()
d2 = dict()

with open('input1.txt', 'r') as file1:
    for row in file1:
        c0, c1 = row.split()[:2]
        d1[c1] = c0
with open('input2.txt', 'r') as file2:
    for row in file2:
        c0, c1 = row.split()[:2]
        d2[(c0, c1)] = [d1[c1], d1[c1]]

#for k, v in sorted(d2.items()):
    #print '\t'.join(v)
print d2

Error:

Key Error: 'key'
```

Its the same error even if for loop is not commented and last print is commented.

Comment: When posting errors here, it is best to post the complete Traceback.  A [KeyError](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.KeyError) occurs when you try to retrieve something from a dictionary that isn't there.  Print statements can help a lot when trying to figure things like this out. Wrap the statement in a Try/Except block and print the offending value and maybe the dictionary.  You may need to strip the whitespace off each row before splitting it. you might want to spend some time with the Tutorial in the docs and maybe http://www.greenteapress.com/thinkpython/

Comment: [8.3. Handling Exceptions](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `d1`, use file1 column 1 for the keys and column 0 for the values creating a lookup table:

```
f1 = [(123,0),(234,1),(345,2),(456,3),(567,4),(678,5)]
f2 = [(0,2),(0,3),(0,5),(2,4),(5,1)]

d1 = {c1:c0 for c0,c1 in f1}
```

That allows you to use file2 column values to *look up* the values in `d1`

```
d2 = {(c0, c1):[d1[c0], d1[c1]] for c0, c1 in f2}
print d2

>>>
{(5, 1): [678, 234], (0, 3): [123, 456], (0, 5): [123, 678], (0, 2): [123, 345], (2, 4): [345, 567]}
>>>
```

***Your code for file 1 and file 2 refactored***:

```
d1, d2 = dict(), dict()
with open('inputfile1.txt', 'r') as file1:
    for row in file1:
        c0, c1 = row.strip().split()[:2]
        d1[c1] = c0

with open('inputfile2.txt', 'r') as file2:
    for row in file2:
        c0, c1 = row.strip().split()[:2]
        d2[(c0, c1)] = [d1[c0], d1[c1]]

>>> for k, v in sorted(d2.items()):
    print '\t'.join(v)


123 345
123 456
123 678
345 567
678 234
>>>
```

Unpacking values/items during assignment:

```
>>> 
>>> x, y, z = [1, 2, 3]
>>> print x, y, z
1 2 3
>>> x, y = [1, 2, 3]

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#259>", line 1, in <module>
    x, y = [1, 2, 3]
ValueError: too many values to unpack
>>> 
>>> a, b, _, _, _, _ = '1 2 3 4 5 6'.split()
>>> print a, b, _
1 2 6
>>>
```

Comment: This looks great and much simpler than what i was trying to write. But i am getting an error: `c0, c1 = row.split()` `ValueError: too many values to unpack`

Comment: That Exception will occur if the file has more than two columns.  I assumed that your files (# 1 and #2) are structured - value whitespace value.  If ```row.split()``` results in more than two items then you may need to refactor and index into the resultant list or ensure that there are enough *names* on the left side of the assignment to account for all of the items in ```row.split()```

Comment: The file has other columns too but we dont have to consider them. So I did not mention just to avoid confusion.

Comment: There are a few ways to handle that.  If you are using Python 3.x you can use extended unpacking -> ```a, b, *c = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]```.  [PEP 3132](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/).   You could directly index the items you need from ```row.split()```.  See the edit for a third option.

Comment: while reading and trying to trace through the code its perfectly correct but yet i am getting key errors. Code updated.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have matching keys because `d1` contains pairs as keys, while `d2` contains single values.

This line looks like it is wrong:

```
    key =  col[0], col[1]
```

Comment: The input file1 has pair of keys and those keys have value in file2 in one column only and i need the output in pair as `[value_of_K1 value_of_K2]`